# Facing Error while importing ktrain that tensorflow has not attribute named swish

Tags: python, jupyter, ktrain

While importing ktrain, I am getting the following error:

`AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.keras.activations' has no attribute 'swish'`

Can anyone please help and tell how to get it going?
The same works fine on google colab.

Full Error:

````
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d851226d5f91> in <module>
----> 1 import ktrain
      2 from ktrain import text

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Anmol/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ktrain/__init__.py in <module>
      1 from .version import __version__
----> 2 from . import imports as I
      3 from .core import ArrayLearner, GenLearner, get_predictor, load_predictor, release_gpu_memory
      4 from .vision.learner import ImageClassLearner
      5 from .text.learner import BERTTextClassLearner, TransformerTextClassLearner

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Anmol/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ktrain/imports.py in <module>
    227 logging.getLogger("transformers").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    228 try:
--> 229     import transformers
    230 except ImportError:
    231     warnings.warn("transformers not installed - needed by various models in 'text' module")

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Anmol/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/__init__.py in <module>
    133 
    134 # Pipelines
--> 135 from .pipelines import (
    136     Conversation,
    137     ConversationalPipeline,

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Anmol/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/pipelines.py in <module>
     46     import tensorflow as tf
     47 
---> 48     from .modeling_tf_auto import (
     49         TF_MODEL_FOR_QUESTION_ANSWERING_MAPPING,
     50         TF_MODEL_FOR_SEQ_TO_SEQ_CAUSAL_LM_MAPPING,

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Anmol/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_auto.py in <module>
     49 from .configuration_utils import PretrainedConfig
     50 from .file_utils import add_start_docstrings
---> 51 from .modeling_tf_albert import (
     52     TFAlbertForMaskedLM,
     53     TFAlbertForMultipleChoice,

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Anmol/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_albert.py in <module>
     22 import tensorflow as tf
     23 
---> 24 from .activations_tf import get_tf_activation
     25 from .configuration_albert import AlbertConfig
     26 from .file_utils import (

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Anmol/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/activations_tf.py in <module>
     52     "gelu": tf.keras.layers.Activation(gelu),
     53     "relu": tf.keras.activations.relu,
---> 54     "swish": tf.keras.activations.swish,
     55     "silu": tf.keras.activations.swish,
     56     "gelu_new": tf.keras.layers.Activation(gelu_new),

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.keras.activations' has no attribute 'swish'  ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Okay so there is some issue with Macs with M1.
Followed the following to resolve the issue:
(https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/48)

- Anaconda start a new environment Uninstall tensorflow & tensorboard
  if exists
- Rename all the files inside the x86_64 folder from 11_0 to    10_16.
- Example: tensorflow_macos-0.1a0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_16_x86_64.whl

In Conda console run below with 'username' replaced with your username:

- pip install pip wheel setuptools cached-property six
- pip install
  "/Users/username/Downloads/tensorflow_macos/x86_64/grpcio-1.33.2-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_16_x86_64.whl"
- pip install
  "/Users/username/Downloads/tensorflow_macos/x86_64/h5py-2.10.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_16_x86_64.whl"
- pip install
  "/Users/username/Downloads/tensorflow_macos/x86_64/numpy-1.18.5-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_16_x86_64.whl"
- pip install
  "/Users/username/Downloads/tensorflow_macos/x86_64/scipy-1.5.4-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_16_x86_64.whl"
- pip install
  "/Users/username/Downloads/tensorflow_macos/x86_64/tensorflow_addons-0.11.2+mlcompute-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_16_x86_64.whl"
- pip install absl-py astunparse flatbuffers gast google_pasta
  keras_preprocessing opt_einsum protobuf tensorflow_estimator
  termcolor typing_extensions wrapt wheel tensorboard typeguard
- pip install
  "/Users/username/Downloads/tensorflow_macos/x86_64/tensorflow_macos-0.1a0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_16_x86_64.whl"

Answer (score 0):

Check the versions that you are using for Tensorflow (and transformers). You can check this issue in GitHub:
https://github.com/amaiya/ktrain/issues/255

I use ktrain==0.25.4 and tensorflow==2.4.1 and everything worked.

Comment: Was on Tensorflow version = 2.0.0
did -> pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
to upgrade tensorflow
after that 
I am getting 
"The kernel for Path/file.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically."
and import tensorflow is not working.

Comment: @AnmolGupta try to uninstall TensorFlow and install it again in a specific version, for example `pip install tensorflow==2.4.1`.